# How to disable wakeup by bluetooth mouse?

Tags: suspend, bluetooth

I have an Asus laptop with Xubuntu 20.04. I am using a Bluetooth mouse.

When the laptop is connected to AC power it wakes up by the mouse.

This is a problem because you can always move a mouse and get the laptop powered on. Then if you unplug power and go, the battery is drained.

Is there a way to disable wakeup by Bluetooth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution.

```
echo XHC > /proc/acpi/wakeup
```

fixes the problem, but it doesn't survive reboots.

This command should be setup in `systemd` as a oneshot service.

Comment: Or use tmpfiles for persistence: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/772229/143394

Answer (score 1):

```
echo XHCI > /proc/acpi/wakeup
```

works on my laptop (Huawei Matebook X Pro 2020). The command toggles the enabled/disabled state for the device which is a USB hub, so it will enable/disable wakeup for all devices attached to USB, which includes Bluetooth on my laptop.

Comment: This is a copy of the accepted answer.

Comment: @Pilot6 seems to contain some useful additional detail

Comment: @Zanna These details look obvious to me. The command really disables wakeup. But you're probably right.

Comment: The only real difference is XHC->XHCI, which is significant if you dont know what XHC is supposed to be. I have also noticed that the initial value of this setting depends on a BIOS setting on my laptop. I would have added a comment instead of posting a new answer, but I was not allowed to ...

Comment: To make it permanent:  https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/772229/143394